# CF10 , MYSQL SQL_SELECT_LIMIT=DEFAULT

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I just set up CF10, win2008, IIS 7.5 with mysql 5.6. But we are getting this error:

```
Error Executing Database Query.
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OPTION SQL_SELECT_LIMIT=DEFAULT
```

This error is removed when I explicitly set "LIMIT" to the queries.

**(Update from comments)**

Here is an example:

```
<cfquery name="dds" datasource ="#Request.Datasource#"> 
    SELECT * 
    FROM   tblaccounts 
    LIMIT 100 
</cfquery>
```

As far as my research shows, it's an incompatibility with the new version of mysql 5.6.

Comment: PL post your query that is giving you the error

Comment: How can we get where the error is without seeing the queries? PL post all the queries

Comment: ok here is an example, 
'<cfquery name="dds" datasource ="#Request.Datasource#">
SELECT * FROM tblaccounts LIMIT 100
</cfquery>' A far as my research shows its an incompatibility with the new version of mysql 5.6.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Borrowing some from the answers above with more detail:

We were having the same problem and it was fixed by updating the JDBC file. Since [ColdFusion 10 only supports MySQL 5.0 and 5.1](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/products/coldfusion/pdfs/cf10/coldfusion10-support-matrix.pdf), you need to update the Connector as mentioned above.

To update the JDBC Connector on your Windows machine,

1. Obtain the .zip connector from [the link provided above](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/)
2. Open the zip archive and locate the mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar
3. Copy this .jar file to C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\lib\
4. Open Services (Start > Control Panel [Optional] > Administrative Tools > Services)
5. Stop/Start the "ColdFusion 10 Application Server" service

To verify the new .jar is has been recognized by ColdFusion, login to your ColdFusion Administrator, click on "Settings Summary" under "Server Settings".  Search for "mysql".  You should see the .jar file listed under the "CF Server Java Class Path" section.  There is no need to re-setup datasources.  These changes should automatically apply.

Comment: Its strange, i had tried this way before posting the question here and it didn't work for me. After this update my datasources were not recognised etc etc and i reverted back to old connector and had to reinstall CF to pick up my datasources. But i just tried this again and works pretty well so far. Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: That first link seems to have been updated as it mentions support for 5.6 now.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand another option should be to update the JDBC driver to the [latest MySQL JDBC Driver](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/). You can find instructions on [using the latest JDBC driver here](http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/coldfusion-mx-configuring-mysql-jdbc.html): (though the instructions may be a bit old, it should still work pretty much the same way).

FYI [ColdFusion 10 only supports MySQL 5.0 and 5.1](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/products/coldfusion/pdfs/cf10/coldfusion10-support-matrix.pdf).

Comment: updating the jdbc driver wont change the fact that `SET OPTION` is invalid in mysql 5.6

Comment: Hi Guys, I did update to the latest driver but it caused all sorts of problems where CF wasn't recognizing the Datasources. @pete right now when i set "Limits" to my queries it all works well, do you think its bad practice? should we invest in downgrading our mysql to 5.1, PS thanks so much for the cf10 lockdown guide, awesome stuff.

Comment: @ChrisBlackwell He is not using SET OPTION in his code, it is done internally by the JDBC Driver

Comment: @indian369 I don't think you would want to add limits to all queries, given that MySQL 5.6 is not supported yet by Adobe I would move to 5.1 which is supported - there could be other issues yet to be found.

Comment: FYI - I contacted some folks at Adobe about this and they asked me to Log a bug for it, so it has been logged as bug #3506758 https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3506758 if you experience this issue please vote for the bug and add any comments that may be helpful to the CF engineering team.

Comment: Oh.. so the issue occurs with *any* query against a 5.6 database? If so, forget my suggestion of using `limit`. I thought it might be related to using `<cfquery maxRows="...>`. But Pete is right, that is not a good fix for this particular problem.

Comment: @PeteFreitag fair shout, that wasn't clear from the error message.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks much Clark - we just had the same issue with CF9

This actually applies to CF9 as well.
Step 3 is then: Copy this .jar file to C:\ColdFusion9\lib\
Step3a Rename the old driver mysql-connector-java-commercial-5.1.11-bin.jar.old
Otherwise drivers may conflict. (happened before)

After the update the bug seemed to be gone. :)

Answer (score 1):

MySQL 5.6 is now supported in ColdFusion 10 update 11, details here: http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/coldfusion-10-update-11.html

Answer (score 0):

MySQL deprecated `SET OPTION` a long time ago, see the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-statement.html), and it was removed in 5.6
You need to use SET without the OPTION statement,

`SET SQL_SELECT_LIMIT = 100;`

Will do what you want.

Be aware that this sets the default for a single connection. To ensure that your subsequent query uses the same connection wrap them in a `<cftransaction>`

```
<cftransaction>
  <cfquery name="tmp" datasource ="#Request.Datasource#"> 
  SET SQL_SELECT_LIMIT = 100;
  </cfquery> 
  <cfquery name="dds" datasource ="#Request.Datasource#"> 
  SELECT * 
  FROM tblaccounts;
  </cfquery> 
</cftransaction>
```

An alternative is to enable multiple queries for the datasource, but this is not recommended for security reasons.

Comment: I would recommend using the standard `limit` operator instead. `sql_select_limit` is a session level setting. Once you apply it, it persists for the life of the db connection. So if connection pooling is enabled, there is a good chance the connection will be reused and the limit applied to a completely unrelated query. It is safer to use the standard `LIMIT` operator instead, because it only applies to the individual query. That said, I am not convinced they are using a `set option ...` explicitly. Granted the original question is not real clear on that - one way or the other.

Comment: It is strange that even the option already deprecated in 5.0 it still being used in MySQL Java Connector for 5.1 (5.1.12). Anyway the latest Connector (5.1.24) has been fixed to not use SET OPTION.